# JSP not rendering - Springboot 2.1.1

Tags: spring-boot

I am using Spring boot 2.1.1 and added following dependencies in gradle file

```
  dependencies {
    implementation(
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web',
            'javax.servlet:jstl',
            'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper',
    )
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix:/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix:.jsp
```

Controller class

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloJsp {

    @RequestMapping(value="/welcome.html",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView Hello(){
        return new ModelAndView("welcome");
    }
}
```

Also I put it jsp file under `/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/`
 and I am getting

> "Whitelabel Error Page" 404 not found error

Am i missing something ?

Comment: please share your controller code and application.properties file

Comment: updated my post

Comment: did you try giving only "/welcome" in your request mapping removing .html extension?

Comment: yes I tried but same error

Comment: seems jsp is not getting compile when tomcat server is started...

Comment: For starters I suggest NOT to use JSP when using an embedded system. It is seriously lacking in features and support (see [the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations)). That being said, make sure you are using a WAR instead of JAR (else it will not work). Also see the JSP sample [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.1.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp/pom.xml) although for Maven it should give some guidance.